# TextEdit line background color

Tags: qt, qml

Is it possible to set up background color for particular line of TextEdit (for instance when line is clicked)?

I will have TextEdit with width:500px and with 10 lines. I will click on line number 5, which is empty line, but i still want to change the background color of whole line. Is it possible?

I need to know if it is possible to develop fully customized code editor with Qt and Qml.

Comment: There nice example of rich editor in qml examples come with `Qt`. It made through a `C++` plugin not pure `QML`. As for your question, what exactly you try to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a solution which relies on text edit's cursor rectangle:

```
FocusScope {
    id: root
    property alias font: textEdit.font
    property alias text: textEdit.text

    Rectangle {
        color: "lightyellow"
        height: textEdit.cursorRectangle.height
        width: root.width
        visible: root.focus
        y: textEdit.cursorRectangle.y
    }

    TextEdit {
        id: textEdit
        anchors.fill: parent
        focus: true
     }
}
```

**Original Answer:**

Here's my proof of concept solution. It is a custom `TextEdit` component which highlights current line. It lacks proper line height calculation, but it can be either hard coded if only one font size is used or obtained from [QFontMetrics](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qfontmetrics.html).

```
import QtQuick 2.3

Item {
    id: root
    property alias font: textEdit.font
    property alias text: textEdit.text

    Column {
        anchors.fill: parent
        Repeater {
            model: root.height / root.lineHeight
            Rectangle {
                color: index === textEdit.currentLine ? "lightyellow" : "transparent"
                height: root.lineHeight
                width: root.width
            }
        }
    }

    TextEdit {
        id: textEdit

        property int currentLine: text.substring(0, cursorPosition).split(/\r\n|\r|\n/).length - 1
        // FIXME: Use proper line height (e.g. from QFontMetrics)
        property int lineHeight: font.pixelSize + 2

        anchors.fill: parent
     }
}
```

If you want to highlight even empty lines, then you need to handle mouse clicks and keypad events and manually change colours of corresponding rectangles.

Comment: i am not sure if it is good idea to have 1:1 mapping from lines to rectangles. You could have 5000 rectangles for 5000 lines.But i will try it.

Comment: @Krab, I have updated my answer with a better solution. It does not create many rectangles and relies on [TextEdit.cursorRectangle](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qml-qtquick-textedit.html#cursorRectangle-prop) property.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cursorRectangle` property of the `TextEdit` and `FontMetrics` for this purpose:

```
Item {
    id: root
    height: te.implicitHeight

    FontMetrics {
        id: fontMetrics
        font: te.font
    }

    Rectangle {
        x: 0; y: te.cursorRectangle.y
        height: fontMetrics.height
        width: te.width
        color: "#e7e7e7"
        visible: te.activeFocus
    }

    TextEdit {
        id: te
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.right: parent.right
        anchors.top: parent.top
    }
}
```

You can [see the result](https://youtu.be/d_XrZyFvKbc) for my commercial project:
[image: My real world editor for an example]